# Objective-C preprocessor directive for 'if not'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I understand how to use a preprocessor directive like this:

```
#if SOME_VARIABLE
    // Do something
#else
    // Do something else
#endif
```

But what if I only want to do something IF NOT SOME_VARIABLE.

Obviously I still could do this:

```
#if SOME_VARIABLE

#else
    // Do something else
#endif
```

. . . leaving the if empty, But is there a way to do:

```
#if not SOME_VARIABLE
   // Do something
#endif
```

Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-4.2.1/cpp/Conditional-Syntax.html#Conditional-Syntax) suggests not, but this seems like a very basic need.

Basically I want to do the preprocessor equivalent of:

```
if(!SOME_VARIABLE)(
{
   // Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

you could try:

```
#if !(SOME_VARIABLE)
   // Do something
#endif
```

Comment: I've removed all references to TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR. That was just an example. I just want to know how to say IF NOT in a preprocessor directive.

Comment: Does the parentheses around SOME_VARIABLE matter?

Answer (score 25):

Are you trying to check if something is defined or not?
If yes, you can try:

`#ifndef SOME_VARIABLE`

or

`#if !defined(SOME_VARIABLE)`

Comment: My question has nothing to do whether it is defined or not. Just wanted a way to do the equivalent if if(!some_var){//do something};

Answer (score 4):

The Apple documentation ([If - The C Preprocessor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-4.2.1/cpp/If.html#If)) is correct and this is the way that C pre-processor statements have been since the dawn of time.  As per that same documentation all you can do is craft an expression that evaluates to either zero or a non-zero value and use that.

Meccan's answers is correct as `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` is defined as `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on the platform, so the expression will evaluate to either zero or a non-zero amount.

In general these macros (`#if` etc) are used for including or excluding things based on whether a symbol is defined or not.  For that use case the pre-processor has `#ifdef` and `#ifndef` which covers what has historically been accepted as the most important cases.

Also given that the subject of these statements can only be other pre-processor defined symbols (via `#define`) then this limitation is reasonable.