# how to have false condition in if has include

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In objective c, How can have false condition in `#if __has_include`?

Like I tried this

```
#if __has_include(!"RNFileViewerManager.h")
```

but it says

> Expected "FILENAME" or < FILENAME >

> Invalid token at start of a preprocessor expression

**Goal**: I am getting duplicate symbol error and I only want to load my code if `RNFileViewerManager` doesn't exist

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880510/objective-c-preprocessor-directive-for-if-not

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to use the method is

```
#if __has_include(<frmaework/filename.h>)
  something *h = [something new]
#else
  other *h = [other new]
#endif
```

Try this and check whether you are getting error or not.